# How to Publish stream using pyfacebook?

Tags: facebook, fbml, pyfacebook

HI,

Can anyone tell me how to publish a story or a news feed on a user profile using pyfacebook, i have used

```
fbml = "<fb:wide><fb:subtitle>This is the subtitle</fb:subtitle>"
fbml += "<fb:if-is-own-profile>This is your profile.<fb:else>This is not your profile.</fb:else></fb:if-is-own-profile></fb:wide>"
```

request.facebook.profile.setFBML(fbml, request.facebook.uid)

return request.facebook.redirect(request.facebook.get_url('profile', id=request.facebook.uid))

and also: (i found it on some forum)

request.facebook.profile.setFBML(fbml, request.facebook.uid, '', '', '', fbml)

return request.facebook.redirect(request.facebook.get_url('profile', id=request.facebook.uid))

it take me to profile page, but doesn't display anything there

I am stuck.... please help me

Answer (score 0):

profile.setFBML is for the box that either appears on the user's wall sidebar or boxes tab (this is going away entirely in the very near future too BTW).

what you want is [stream.publish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish).